# Iterate over rows and subtract values in pandas df

Tags: pandas, loops

I have the following table:

| ID | Qty_1 | Qty_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 10 |
| A | 2 | 0 |
| A | 3 | 0 |
| B | 3 | 29 |
| B | 2 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 0 |

I want to iterate based on the ID, and subtract Qty_2 - Qty_1 and update the next row with that result.

The result would be:

| ID | Qty_1 | Qty_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 10 |
| A | 2 | 8 |
| A | 3 | 5 |
| B | 3 | 29 |
| B | 2 | 27 |
| B | 1 | 26 |

Ideally, I would also like to start by subtracting the first row end a new ID appears and only after that start the loop:

| ID | Qty_1 | Qty_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 9 |
| A | 2 | 7 |
| A | 3 | 4 |
| B | 3 | 26 |
| B | 2 | 24 |
| B | 1 | 23 |

Each of the solutions is ok! Thank you!

Comment: Since SO is not a code-writing site, what attempt have you made, and what research have you done?

Comment: I manage to reach that table, and use the indexes to replace the Qty_2 by 0 and leave the first row of each ID with a Qty >0.

Now, I want to try something like while ID is the same, subtract Qty_2(ith row)-Qty_1(i+1 row). A while loop maybe?

Comment: Please create a [reprex] with your current code, and also see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First compute the difference between 'Qty_1' and 'Qty_2' row by row, then group by 'ID' and compute cumulative sum:

```
df['Qty_2'] = df.assign(Qty_2=df['Qty_2'].sub(df['Qty_1'])) \
                .groupby('ID')['Qty_2'].cumsum()
print(df)

# Output:
  ID  Qty_1  Qty_2
0  A      1      9
1  A      2      7
2  A      3      4
3  B      3     26
4  B      2     24
5  B      1     23
```

Setup:

```
data = {'ID': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
        'Qty_1': [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1],
        'Qty_2': [10, 0, 0, 29, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Legend! Thank you